# how to implement preferenceactivity in activity extending from application

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

How can I do to implement a preferenceactivity in a class that does not extend from activity to application, I share a bit of my code:

This is my MainClass AppBeacon:

```
public class appBeacon extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
some code...
}
```

This is the preferenceactivity class:

public class PreferenceActivity extends android.preference.PreferenceActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.activity_preference);

   ...some code
        }
    });
}
```

}

How to implement my preference activity in Appbeacon??

Comment: firstly , application classes are singletons for initialisations and configuration, not activity based. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to set a PreferenceActivity on mi appBeacon class I´ve tried with this: `Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);` Error: cannot resolve method startActivityForResult, I've tried with startActivity(i) but every time I open the app the preferenceActivity class appears and don´t save my preferences